# Alignment of text on button

Tags: android, button, alignment

I am creating a custom button. I want to set the position of text on button.

- I have two background images for button (button_off and button_on) first is for normal button and second is for onFocus / onPressed state.

[image]
[image]

- Now I have to put text on button then it should look like:

[image]
[image]

But i am unable to set the exact position of the text on this background button image.
Please share your suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: follow this link [Buttons](http://www.androidpeople.com/button) , u will get answer here. and surf through this website u will learn alot

Comment: I can't find the answer on the linked page. And besides, I think it's bad style to post a link/article collection as an answer to a specific question. If the answer can be found somewhere among the articles, just link directly to the article, at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using 9-patch image as a background. More information on this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: But as you can see in that button image text is not in the center of Button. that is 5 pixel more then center. So how to do that?

Comment: When you use 9-patch as a background, you manually (with Google's "draw9patch" tool) define the area which is stretchable, and the area where your text will appear. I think it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can set these properties in XML file, `

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
    android:text="All" 
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Align the text , use gravity option ! or try with padding

Comment: we can use padding only for layout not for text. by setting gravity we can set only left/ right / top /bottom /center alignment. but i want to set text 5 pixel more then center..

Comment: I am able to use padding even for text !

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_all_bg"
    android:text="All">
 Button>
```

You can use the drawableLeft/right/top/bottom to add icon on a button and text would automatically adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways :

1. define a button and try `android:drawableStart`
2. extend Button and draw yourself
3. try to define a `LinearLayout` that hold a text and an image with a
   background of your button,
       set both of them weight of 1 and put them inside another `LinearLayout` and make them `onClick`
       can't assure 3 will work without a tweak or two but it worth trying

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layout as a button `style="@android:style/Widget.Button"`, and configure it as you want.

Paste this in your xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/button"
style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```